# Issues with regex match, too many matches

Tags: java, regex

I have a three regexes, one of each should match their pattern, but for now they match more than their own patter :

```
1. Input: test 1-2-22
regex ^([a-z|A-Z|\s]*)(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)$
I want to capture "test", "1", "2" and "22" in groups

2. Input: ooi 4-11-58 test^two^ one 1 two
regex ^([a-z|A-Z|\s]*)(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)(.+)$
I want to capture "ooi", "4", "11", "58", "test^two^ one 1 two" in groups

3. Input: one two three 3-11 four and five T1 F
regex ^([a-z|A-Z|\s]*)(\d*)-(\d*)(.+)$
I want to capture "one two three", "3", "11", "four and five T1 F" in groups
```

I'm applying each regex on each input string and it should only pass one of those.

What happens now is that regex 1 is match for both 2 and 3 and regex 2 matches the one and all of them each with one another.

How can I correct regexes so each match only their own pattern?

Comment: Why do you use the `^` in front of the regex? Doesn't it negate the following expression (in the brackets)?

Comment: @yasen No, it means "begins with".

Comment: `[a|b]` will match `a`, `|`, `b`. Don't use `|` inside `[...]` unless you want it to also match `|`.

Comment: Regex 1 cannot match #2 and #3, because it requires the string to end in either a dash or a digit.

Comment: @yasen: `^` only negates the characted set specified when it is used within `[`...`]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String regex_0 = "^([a-zA-Z]+)\\s+(\\d+)-(\\d+)-(\\d+)$";

String regex_1 = "^([a-zA-Z]+)\\s+(\\d+)-(\\d+)-(\\d+)\\s+([a-zA-Z0-9\\s]+)$"

String regex_2 = "^([a-zA-Z\\s]+)(\\d+)-(\\d+)\\s+([a-zA-Z0-9\\s]+)$"
```

Note: `[a|b]` as a character class does **not** mean `"a or b"`, it means `"a or b or |"`.
Also, not sure if you actually want `*` or not, as they mean any amount, from what I can tell, it seems like you want `+`, which means one or more.

Answer (score 1):

Dot `.` is too permissive, it would capture anything - including dashes and digits. That is why your third expression matches all three - the `.+` in it matches `"-58 test^two^ one 1 two"` text of the second pattern, or `"-21"` of the first pattern.

You need to add some markers to your regex to distinguish between the patterns. For example, you could modify your #3 to say that the first character of the `.+` must be something other than a dash or a digit, like this:

```
^([a-zA-Z\s]*)(\d*)-(\d*)([^\d-].*)$
```

Note the `[^\d-]` group that I added. It says that the first character in what has been a `.+` in your expression must *not* be a digit or a dash. This would prevent the #3 from capturing a #1 or #2.

Also note that I removed the vertical bars inside the character class, because it is interpreted literally inside square brackets.